# Recently, Fire cloud messaging SDK for Python returns error "Requested entity was not found."

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase_admin SDK to use firebase cloud messaging from Python
This code worked a couple months ago.
but now it returns two error code.
I confirmed `myproject-id` included in the error message is correct.

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:
>   `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{myproject-id}/messages:send`
>
> firebase_admin.messaging.ApiCallError: Requested entity was not found.

I tried to reinstall firebase_admin but nothing changed.

Could you give me some advice?

```py
class fbMessaging():
    def __init__(self):
        cred = credentials.Certificate('./env/firebase.json')
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    def send_to_device(self, text, token):
        message = messaging.Message(
        notification=messaging.Notification(title = title, body = body),
        token=token)
        response = messaging.send(message)
        return response

def main():
    fm = fbMessaging()
    res = fm.send_to_device('test', 'MY CORRECT TOKEN')
    print(res)
```